# how to set new variable in dataframe using mind(dates)

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm trying to define a new variable in my dataframe from two other date columns, both of the two date columns are `datetime` variables

```
df['date_new'] = max(df['date1'], df['date2'])
```

the error returns:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you are trying to use Python's ***builtin*** `max` function with two pandas Series. Doing this would try to determine the maximum `Series` between `df['date1']` and `df['date2']`, which does not really make sense. Use the [`pandas.DataFrame.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) method instead.

What you are looking for is to determine the maximum `datetime` value by row of `df[['date1', 'date2']]`, and the following is a very good way to get that done:

```
df['date_new'] = df[['date1', 'date2']].max(axis=1)
```

I hope this helps.